# Couldn't understand the difference in the timing of three similar JavaScript code snippets

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was recently experimenting around with arrays in JavaScript when I got to know about a concept called ***sparse arrays***. I decided to explore the concept in extreme detail.

I timed two pieces of code and got some interesting results:

The following code took roughly around **2 seconds** to complete:

Code 1:

```
var arr = new [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
    arr[i] + 10;
}
```

However, the code below (which is exactly the same as before except for the value assigned to `arr`) took around **7 seconds**!

Code 2:

```
var arr = new Array(100000000);
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
    arr[i] + 10;
}
```

Now I reasoned to myself that the second code creates a sparse array which is internally implemented as an object (where the numbers are stored as properties on the object, not as indexes i.e. `arr` works like a hash table), therefore it takes longer to complete than the first code snippet.

To support my reasoning I run a similar code, but this time using a plain JavaScript object:

Code 3:

```
var obj = {}
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    obj[i] = i;
    obj[i] + 10;
}
```

To my suprise, this completes in around **5 seconds**!

Could anyone please briefly explain me how is each of these snippets implemented internally so that I could make intuition behind the time taken by each one?

From the results, I think that `new Array(100000000)` is not implemented as a native JavaScript object. So then how is it implemented?

Comment: This will completely depend on the engine, so while current v8 may show this behavior, it is already not true of SpiderMonkey, and might not be true in v8 in a few months either. But yeah, current v8 really doesn't like sparse-arrays as they can't optimize it through their shape recognition strategy (they don't know of what is made the Array). In the first case, they treat it as an array of SMIs all along, which is super fast. I guess if you added one string like at the index 100 during your loop, then even the first would take far longer to proceed.

Comment: @Kaiido could you explain what do you mean by *I guess if you added one string like at the index 100...*?

Comment: by adding a string in the middle of this array of small numbers, the js engine would have to deoptimize the array completely.

Comment: You mean, use a conditional to check for `i == 100` and then push a string into the array inside the conditional's body?

Comment: I tried doing so but the time difference compared to the original version was just a hundred milliseconds.

Comment: @Kaiido I have more thing in my mind, I would like if you could help me on that. Since arrays (regardless of the fact whether they are sparse or dense) have to maintain a `length` property as compared to native objects, is this one of the reasons why Code 2 above performs poor than Code 3?

Comment: https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds#packed-vs.-holey-kinds